# .C Interface to R

Tags: c, windows, r

I'm following this guide:
http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/interface.pdf

I want to create code copiled in C to use it in R
So I created my hello.c file:

```
#include <R.h>
void hello(int *n)
{
int i;
for(i=0; i < *n; i++) {
Rprintf("Hello, world!\n");
}
}
```

And I saved it in c:\temp
Having done that, I must then compile the C code.

I honestly don't have any idea what I'm doing but I'm tring to write in windows cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\
R CMD SHLIB c:\temp\hello.c
```

And I get the error:

> cygwin warning:   MS-DOS style path detected:
>   C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf   Preferred POSIX equivalent
>   is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/i386/Makeco nf   CYGWIN
>   environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
>   Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
>       http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames make: *** No rule to make target `c:\temp\hello.o', needed by`c:\temp\hello.dll '.  Stop.

This should create a file names "hello.so". So I can call it in R with:

```
        dyn.load("hello.so")

        hello2 <- function(n) {
                                .C("hello", as.integer(n))
                           }

        hello2(5)
```

But my command doesn't create the hello.so file.
Maybe I need to install another compiler, but I can't install software in the PC that I'm using. Is there a way to do it with the windows cmd? Where is my mistake?

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in [Appendix D: The Windows Toolset](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) of the R Installation and Administration manual.

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987667/r-external-interface with some other resources

Comment: I think `.C` is going away soon. Dirk mentions it in his answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453373/function-c-argument-setup-fails-compilation. Recommending `.Call` and `.External` instead

Comment: Not going away (as in: existing interfaces remain available) but stronger and stronger recommendations against use -- `.C()` is limited whereas `.Call()` allows full objects access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `C:\temp\hello.c` exists try this from the windows cmd line (carefully checking that Rtools, R and the paths used exist):

```
cd c:\temp
path C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;%ProgramFiles%\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64;%path%
R CMD SHLIB hello.c
Rgui
```

Now in R:

```
dyn.load("hello.dll")
.C("hello", 3L)
```

**Note:** Also there are some batch files here that may help:

http://batchfiles.googlecode.com

http://code.google.com/p/batchfiles/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

See `Rpathset.bat`, `R.bat` and the documentation `batchfiles.md` .

**Update** Corrections and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question *directly*, but have you looked into the `Rcpp` package, which allows for C++ to be integrated (called from) R? It might make life a lot easier for you, depending upon what you are doing.

Look [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/), and also at the [R docs](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) and this from a [presentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rcpp_rfinance_may2014.pdf) by Dirk E

Comment: That won't help because they don't have the necessary tools required to build C/C++ code from source.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich But after installing the `Rtools` this should be possible right?

Comment: No...as OP says cannot install software...missed that. Thank @Joshua